# Updating an older app version in the Playstore while a new version is in staged rollout

Tags: android, apk, developer-console

I have an app in the Playstore for which I plan to release a major update - lets call them version 1.0 and version 2.0. I would like to do so via a staged rollout, so that I can control the percentage of users who will receive the version 2.0 update. The staged rollout phase may take several months before I decide to release it to 100% of the users.

I would like to know if it is possible to release a small update for version 1.0 once I have begun the staged rollout of version 2.0. I assume (correct me if I'm wrong) that if I upload an apk of version 1.1, then all of the users in the staged rollout group will receive this new update, and therefor switch from 2.0 to 1.1 - this is obviously not desirable. Is that what will happen? And if so, is there any way around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly occurs this you say and you have two different vias to solve this:

- The first one is to upload 1.1 on production, for all users and 2.0 in beta for  one or multiple groups of people and after time that you want, then upgrade 2.0 to production.
- The second via is upgrade first to 1.1 on production and later upgrade to 2.0 with staged rollout.

Tell me if I helped you, regards!

Comment: But if I have 2.0 in beta, would I still be able to release updates for 1.0 (1.1, 1.2, 1.3 etc) during the beta phase? Because according to the alpha/beta documentation I believe the beta 2.0 users would automaticaly switch once I upload a new apk:

"If a Production APK is uploaded with a higher version code than an alpha or beta APK, the alpha and/or beta version will automatically be deactivated."

Comment: As for the second option you proposed - the problem is I don't know yet when/if I'll need to release any fixes to version 1.0. But it would be good to know if I actually can do so.

Comment: The answer is yes, you can have the superior API in beta, and continue upgrading versions in production as 1.1, 1.2, etc. And how you said, when you upload production version superior than beta, the beta will be obsolete. With your second answer, I think your best option is the first, because you don't know when you can repair the bugs.

Comment: Ok so beta is an alternative option. However, I'd really like to force a substantial portion of my users to try out the 2.0 version, without them thinking the new features are experimental. That's why I'd really prefer to use a staged rollout.

Comment: Then use the normal way, update your app to 2.0 and upload after new versions to solve problems. 
Please remember, to give the check if it has resolved your doubt, regards!